# NSPanel HUD with title and close button

Tags: cocoa

I'm having difficulties trying to create a HUD-style NSPanel similar to the one used in VLC's equalizer ([image here](http://fairerplatform.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/vlc-media-player-2-dune.jpg)). To start, I want the see through panel with a close button and title.  This is the code I am trying to use to achive th

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    NSPanel *panel = [[NSPanel alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(200.0, 200.0, 300, 200)
                                                styleMask:NSHUDWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSTitledWindowMask
                                                  backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                    defer:YES];

    [panel makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
}
```

The `NSHUDWindowMask` param clearly works, I get a gray seethrough panel.  But, the `NSClosableWindowMask` param seems to do nothing (no close button) and the `NSTitledWindowMask` produces the following runtime error:

> Window styleMask 0x2003 is not supported for a Heads Up Display window

As far as I can tell from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nspanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000244-DontLinkElementID_3), this mask combination should be allowed.  I have tried this with both OS X 10.7 and 10.8 sdks.  Does anyone know how to achieve this style window along with the close / title buttons?

Answer (score 7):

That documentation link you posted appears to indicate that you need to include `NSUtilityWindowMask` in the mask as well.